# SQL percentage aggregation over group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that gives the following sql query inputs gives.

```
select server, count(*) from ServerNames where server is not null and server != '' and timestamp >= '2015-03-18'
and timestamp <= '2015-04-19' group by server;

Server | Count(*)
_________________
Server1    1700  
Server2    1554

select server, ip_address, count(*) from serverNames where server is not null and server != '' and ip_address is not null and ip_address != '' and timestamp >= '2015-03-18'
and timestamp <= '2015-04-19'  group by server, ip_address;

Server |    ip_address      | count(*)
______________________________________
Server1  Sample_ip_1            14
Server2  Sample_ip_2           209
Server1  Sample_ip_2           100
Server1  Sample_ip_1            50
```

I am finding difficulty in writing a query that calculates percentage within the group . So for instance in my example the output should be.

```
Server | ip_address | Count(*) | percent
________________________________________________
Server1  Sample_ip_1  14         0.82% (14/1700)
Server2  Sample_ip_2 209         13.44%(209/1554)
Server1  Sample_ip_2 100         5.88%(100/1700)
Server2  Sample_ip_1  50         3.217(15/1554)
```

How can I write a query to do that?

Comment: The count(*) from the second output / count(*) from the first.

Comment: join the two queries and calculate percent that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join the results from your two queries together, and then `concat` a bunch of stuff together to get the `percent` value that you're looking for. I think this should do it.

```
select q2.server, q2.ip_address, concat(round((q2.c / q1.c) * 100, 2), '%(', q2.c, '/', q1.c, ')') as percent 
  from
    (
      select server, count(*) c 
        from ServerNames 
        where server is not null 
          and server != '' 
          and timestamp >= '2015-03-18'
          and timestamp <= '2015-04-19' 
        group by server
     ) q1
     inner join
     (
       select server, ip_address, count(*) c  
         from serverNames 
         where server is not null 
           and server != '' 
           and ip_address is not null 
           and ip_address != '' 
           and timestamp >= '2015-03-18'
           and timestamp <= '2015-04-19'  
         group by server, ip_address
     ) q2
     on q1.server = q2.server
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29637/3)

Answer (score 0):

I will, for the sake of this example, suggest selecting each of those queries into intermediary tables, A and B respectively. I don't know what the `count(*)` values represent, so I will call them numerator and denominator respectively.

```
SELECT
    A.Server, B.ip_address, B.numerator, (B.numerator * 100.0) / A.denominator
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.Server = B.Server
```